# Регулярные выражения. Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Как проверить определенный символ в строке?
Например:
В строке проверить 15 символ чтобы он был "z" "k" или "9" и выдать true.

Не могу никак найти ни одного пример проверки именно определенного символа с помощью регулярок.

Comment: а обязательно регулярки использовать?

Comment: да, в универе поставили такую задачу

Comment: Прочитайте описание метки [tag:регулярные-выражения]. Нужны примеры текстов и что в них найти

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
^.{14}[zk9].*$
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5avo7

> 123456789abcdefg
>
> **123456789abcdezg**
>
> **123456789abcde9g**

Comment: Та за шо минус?